# Java - saving data to hashmap

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap, save

I have big problem with figuring this out.
My database (clients.txt) looks like this:

```
Tom;Test1;1000000.00;58010168302;63481000-10000090;1111;2000000.00;1000000.00
John;Test2;1000000.00;58010158125;63481000-10000091;2222;2000000.00;1000000.00
```

From the left:

```
 name;surname;balance;pesel;cardNumber;pin;dailyLimit;maxDebit
```

I have simply DataBase class with private fields, getters, setters and DataBaseHandler class, which reads clients.txt and makes my HashMap:

```
public static Map<Integer, DataBase> data = new HashMap<Integer, DataBase>();
private static Scanner scanner;

public static void read() {

    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("db/clients.txt"));
        int i = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] columnData = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
            data.put(i, new DataBase(columnData[0], 
                                     columnData[1],
                                     columnData[2],
                                     columnData[3], 
                                     columnData[4], 
                                     columnData[5], 
                                     columnData[6], 
                                     columnData[7]));
            i++;
        }
```

This is client-server application (simulator of ATM), so I'm calling read() function in ATMServer class and I'm operating (read) on that data in ATMProtocol class (which extends DataBaseHandler). Where is my problem? In making payment function. I want to simply change the value of balance or create whole new line with new amount of balance and delete older and save it to clients.txt file. I've read about serialization so I've made that function:

```
private String payment(String frameNum,
                       String cardNum,
                       String pinNum,
                       String amount) {
    /* something less important
    String answer = null;
    double localAmount = Double.parseDouble(amount);
    double newAmount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        if(cardNum.equals(data.get(i).getCardNumber())
                && pinNum.equals(data.get(i).getPin())
                && checkAmount(localAmount, i)) {

            newAmount = Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).getBalance()) - localAmount;
            String newAmountString = String.valueOf(newAmount); */
            DataBase dbBase = new DataBase(data.get(i).getName(),
                                            data.get(i).getSurname(),
                                            newAmountString,
                                            data.get(i).getPesel(),
                                            data.get(i).getCardNumber(),
                                            data.get(i).getPin(),
                                            data.get(i).getDailyLimit(),
                                            data.get(i).getMaxDebit());

            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("db/clients.txt",true);

                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

                out.writeObject(dbBase);
                out.close();
                fileOut.close();

            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

After running this app clients.txt looks like this:

```
Tom;Test1;1000000.00;58010168302;63481000-10000090;1111;2000000.00;1000000.00
John;Test2;1000000.00;58010158125;63481000-10000091;2222;2000000.00;1000000.00
cardNumberq
dailyLimitq
2000000.00t
1000000.00t
```

What's most supprising is that when I copied four last rows and pressed ctrl+v it would paste only

```
cardNumberq
```

line. Is it problem with encoding? How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard Java serialization mechanism does not produce semi-colon separated text. It produces a little bit more complicated binary format. When you tried to open your file to append (see `true` flag that you send to `FileOutputStream`) and then write to your text file some binary information you actually get file where the head is text and then some binary information appears. Then you open the file using text editor. It manages to interpret some binary information as a kind of text that you see. This is the reason that copy/paste does not work.

Now what to do. If you want to continue working with your custom format I'd recommend you to create utility class that reads such strings, separates them into fields and creates instnaces of class `DataBase` and write method that creates string from your instance.

If you want to use standard serialization just use it and forget about your format.

If you want to use format and combine it with serialization you have to customize serialization mechanism for your class. To do this implement methods `readObject()` and `writeObject()`. For details read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html).

Comment: Thank you for answer. This is my first "big" project in java, so it's nice to learn from such people like you :)